# simple extension with algebraic over the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Assume that $F$ is infinite, that $v,w \in K$ are algebraic over $F$, and that $w$ is a root of a separable polynomial in $F[x]$. How will I be able to prove that $F(v,w)$ is a simple extension of $F$?

Comment: Refer to the proof of Theorem 22.1.18 of the book "D.S. Malik, J.N. Mordeson and M.K. Sen, Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra". The mentioned theorem is exactly your question.